# intellij tomcat deploy issues

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

Getting this weird message when trying to deploy to tomcat7 from intellij ultimate. You will notice on the INFO line that the path is totally wrong. Where is it getting this from and how can i fix it?

```
Apr 03, 2013 12:38:26 PM org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext doLookup
    INFO: The name [/WEB-INF/classes/C:\dev\apps\admin\newjdbcprops/xvdev.oracle.properties\] is not valid
    javax.naming.InvalidNameException: /WEB-INF/classes/C:\dev\apps\admin\newjdbcprops/xvdev.oracle.properties\: unescaped \ at end of component
        at javax.naming.NameImpl.extractComp(NameImpl.java:161)
        at javax.naming.NameImpl.<init>(NameImpl.java:284)
    ...
```

Comment: IDEA version? Looks like your web application artifact is broken or configured incorrectly. Try to set up a new artifact. If it doesn't help, file a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: intellij 12 (latest). Well you would think, but the project runs just fine using Spring Tools Suite (eclipse) and the built in Tomcat it provides.

Comment: Of course it runs externally, the problem is with IDEA artifact configuration.

Comment: I understand. Where would i find that configuration?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey Did you ever find what was causing it? I'm seeing the same thing. If so, please add an answer for all of us in the future.

Comment: @Noremac I am sure I figured out what the problem was, but for the life of me can't remember. It was a long time ago...

Answer (score 0):

OK.This seems the java constants pool size happens to be 005c.

```
There are 10 basic sections to the Java Class File structure:
Magic Number: 0xCAFEBABE
Version of Class File Format: the minor and major versions of the class file
Constant Pool: Pool of constants for the class
Access Flags: for example whether the class is abstract, static, etc.
This Class: The name of the current class
Super Class: The name of the super class
Interfaces: Any interfaces in the class
Fields: Any fields in the class
Methods: Any methods in the class
Attributes: Any attributes of the class (for example the name of the sourcefile, etc.)
```

So actually your Constant Pool size is 5c.
I suggest you add a const just like

```
 private String avoidInvalidNameException = "unescaped \\ at end of component";
```

Then your pool size may changed.
So Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue as well.
Please check if there are a blank file in mapper files.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this porblem as well and i solved the problem ,mostly the web application artifact is broken or configured incorrectly. check it by two setps:

- check the `Project Structure-->Modules`,if the module name is different with the pom.xml file,you can delete the module,then it will auto generate a config(if you don't know the correct config,you can refer to another project in your computer)
- make sure you artifacts,you must chose the war exploded,not the war only.